# Change query LEFT JOIN to FULL OUTER JOIN (respecting null values) - how to change this (without horrible performance afterwards)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, entity-attribute-value

Having an Entity-Attribute Value setup table which is structured like this (it is from a third party plugin, I can not change the database design):

[image: Table]

Now I want to create a table whith `data_id` being the id, the names being the columns and the values being their values. Still every `data_id` does not have a value for every name therefore I want the value in the result to be NULL (or empty) in case there is no value for this name within the original table.

Now I have written a PHP script which is generating the required query for me:

```
$ihash = function($len = 10){
        return substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 10)), 0, 10);
    };
$columns = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."cf7_vdata_entry");

$fromselects = [];
$left_joins = [];
$wheres = [];
$used=[];

foreach($columns as $column) {
    $m = $ihash();
    while(in_array($m,$used)) {
        $m = $ihash();
    }
    array_push($used,$m);
    array_push($fromselects,"$m.value as `$column`");
    $left_joins  .= " LEFT JOIN wp_cf7_vdata_entry AS $m ON a.data_id = $m.data_id ";
    array_push($wheres,"$m.name = '$column'");
}

$query = "SELECT a.data_id, ".implode(", ",$fromselects)."
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT data_id FROM wp_cf7_vdata_entry) AS a JOIN
  ".$left_joins."
 WHERE ".implode(" AND ",$wheres);
```

This is how a generated query looks like:

```
SELECT a.data_id, 
       vtddnqrdjy.value AS `foerderung`, 
       fwfyxgczvn.value AS `company`, 
       jwlpmnbepe.value AS `firstname`,
       -- ... more fields
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT data_id 
        FROM   wp_cf7_vdata_entry) AS a 
       JOIN wp_cf7_vdata_entry AS vtddnqrdjy 
         ON a.data_id = vtddnqrdjy.data_id 
       JOIN wp_cf7_vdata_entry AS fwfyxgczvn 
         ON a.data_id = fwfyxgczvn.data_id 
       JOIN wp_cf7_vdata_entry AS jwlpmnbepe 
         ON a.data_id = jwlpmnbepe.data_id 
       -- ... more joins
WHERE  vtddnqrdjy.name = 'foerderung' 
       AND fwfyxgczvn.name = 'company' 
       AND jwlpmnbepe.name = 'firstname' 
       AND mloxjygcqp.name = 'lastname' 
       -- ... more fields
LIMIT  10
```

The result table is generated correctly, but the result is empty:

[image: result table]

The reason is that results which do not have ALL column values are filtered out, but they should have null values instead (having **exactly one result** for each data_id existing in the table). I was thinking about replacing all `LEFT JOIN`s with `FULL OUTER JOIN`s (which has to be faked in MySQL), but this is overcomplicating things and the probably already bad performance will be extremly bad than. How could I solve this?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Paraphrase or quote from other text. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Learn what LEFT JOIN ON returns: INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of an OUTER JOIN. A WHERE or INNER JOIN ON that requires a right [sic] table column to be not NULL after an OUTER JOIN ON removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN ON rows, ie "turns OUTER JOIN into INNER JOIN". You have that.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: @philipxy Thanks for the information on JOINs I should refresh my knowledge (I only write queries occassionally). I tried to ask my question as clear and minimal as possible though, I added the PHP to clarify how this query is generated. I may shorten the full query though as in the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. But it is better to avoid a layer or as much code as possible using a layer if you can. Isolate errors in debugging & asking. So a question that only uses SQL is better until you know your SQL is OK. To avoid PHP in your question you could initialize your tables using PHP, select their values, convert that output to SQL initialization code using a tool like 'Text to DDL' at sqlfiddle.com SQL then either use only SQL in your question or use just enough PHP to submit that initialization & your problem query.

Comment: @philipxy Basically I think my question is pretty clear, the challenge was how to query an eav table into a result tables where the "names" are columns and the "values" are the contents of the columns. The PHP is just supplementary information on how the query is generated, I added it for 2 reasons: In case somebody comes up with an SQL-only solution and also to make clear that I have control over the PHP and generate the query in a different way.

Comment: I don't understand the point of your comment. I am just saying that 1. I don't understand what you are trying to say by "I may shorten the full query though as in the answer?" & 2. the more you isolate the problem & make it easy to run code, the more help you will get. I originally mentioned [mre]s because you don't give minimal cut & paste & runnable text.

Comment: For a running example I would have to post the create table structures and commands for seeding the database. I just thought it is easer to understand and illustrate with images. Still this is not an SQL only question, an answer could have involved PHP for query generation. Anyway the accepted answer solved the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support `FULL OUTER JOIN`.  Instead, use aggregation:

```
SELECT de.data_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN de.name = 'foerderung' THEN de.value END) as foerderung, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN de.name = 'company' THEN de.value END) as company
           . . .   -- just repeat for each column
FROM wp_cf7_vdata_entry de
GROUP BY de.data_id;
```

Comment: Just removed 2 typos, works like a charm and much better than my first try, thanks!